# React - Post Request does not work on mobile

Tags: reactjs, post, fetch

I'm trying to submit some simple data to my server.  Everything works fine - on my desktop.  When i try on my mobile (same network) it does not work.  The page just refreshes but the POST request fails (not sure if it fails because i can't open a console on my mobile).  It seems like the page refreshes before it actually gets to the fetch command but i'm not sure and not sure how to troubleshoot because it is working fine on my desktop.  Please help!  Thanks :)

```
  const onSubmit = (event) => {
    const data = {
      price: price,
      gallons: gallons,
      miles: miles,
      notes: notes,
      source: params.car_source,
    };

    const options = {
      method: "POST",
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
      },
      body: JSON.stringify(data),
    };

    fetch(`${process.env.REACT_APP_API_BASE_URL}/consumption/`, options);
  };
```

Comment: what does `process.env.REACT_APP_API_BASE_URL` resolve to?

Comment: if it is working on desktop fine you can check Browser compatibility https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Response and also you can use for support https://polyfill.io/v3/

Comment: It looks like this is a form, by  default submitting forms in some situations causes page to refresh. You need to prevent this default behaviour so you can implement custom `onSubmit` functionality, usually it's something like `event.preventDefault()` at the top of the handler

Comment: process.env.REACT_APP_API_BASE_URL - this is just an env variable that resolves to the url.  in this case: http://localhost:3000/consumption.
i don't think there is a browser issue because i can put event.preventDefault() there and it will work.  However, I want the behavior that the page refreshes so the user can see the data just entered.  however i want it to wait until the POST call has been made :)

Answer (score 0):

This will work! Try this out, Just added `event.preventDefault()` in `handleSubmit` function.

**I follow this [link](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/remote-debugging) for Debugging in mobile.**

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';

function NameForm() {
  const [name, setName] = useState('');
  const handleSubmit = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();

    const data = {
      price,
      gallons,
      miles,
      notes,
      source: params.car_source,
    };

    const options = {
      method: 'POST',
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      },
      body: JSON.stringify(data),
    };

    fetch(`${process.env.REACT_APP_API_BASE_URL}/consumption/`, options);
  };

  const handleChange = (event) => {
    setName(event.target.value);
  };

  return (
    <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
      <label>
        Name:
        <input type="text" value={name} onChange={handleChange} />
      </label>
      <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
    </form>
  );
}

export default NameForm;
```

Comment: event.preventDefault() does make the POST request go through but i want the behavior where the screen refreshes so the user can see the data they just entered.  Unfortunately i have an iOS device :/